# How to setup Gitlab webhook for private domain/url?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, gitlab, amazon-eks

I deployed Gitlab CE in EC2 instance in AWS and acted as our Code Source Repository.

Then I have deployed Jenkins in EKS cluster and setup ingress. Jenkins subdomain is private and accessible within the VPC the routing is IP based.

I need to setup the webhook in Gitlab. However, Gitlab can't reached/access the Jenkins private subdomain.

How can I setup the Gitlab webhook for private domian/url?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your GitLab project.
Navigate to Settings > Integrations.
Expand the Web hooks section.
Click on Add web hook.
Enter the URL of your private domain where you want to receive the web hook payloads. Let's assume your endpoint URL is https://example.com/gitlab-webhook.
Optionally, set a Secret Token for added security.
In this example, whenever there's a new code push in your GitLab repository, GitLab will send a JSON payload to https://example.com/gitlab-webhook. The Flask application running on your server will capture this payload, allowing you to process the data as per your requirements. Remember to adapt the processing logic inside the gitlab_webhook function to suit your use case.

Comment: from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/gitlab-webhook', methods=['POST'])
def gitlab_webhook():
    data = request.get_json()  # Get the JSON payload sent by GitLab
    # Process the data as needed
    # For example, print the payload to the console
    print(data)
    return 'Webhook received successfully!', 200
    if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)

Comment: I tried this setup. However, Gitlab seem's can't reached the private subdomain of jenkins.  I'm not sure if I needed Network Load Balancer for Jenkins or something.